# XDocument.Load(XmlReader) Possible Exceptions

Tags: c#, xml, exception, linq-to-xml

What are the possible exceptions that can be thrown when `XDocument.Load(XmlReader)` is called?  It is hard to follow best practices (i.e. avoiding generic try catch blocks) when the documentation fails to provide crucial information.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Are there possibly some exceptions that you *wouldn't* want to catch?  If this is a UI, then an exception (*any* exception) means a failure and you won't be able to load the document and you'll have to show an error message to the user.  If it's more server-side then again, *any* exception means a failure you aren't likely to recover from, so the best you can do is wrap it in another exception and provide some context for when it bubbles up to your global exception handler.

Comment: I wouldn't want to catch stackoverflow or OutOfMemory exceptions, for example.  I want to know what exceptions can be expected so I can deal with them locally.  Anything else can bubble up to my global exception handler for logging.  I know there are many different schools of thought on exception handling.  I am new to development (8mos total, only 2mos full-time), so I am still processing all of this.  However, regardless the school to which one adheres, I think it seems reasonable to wish that the possible exceptions were actually documented.  We can probably all agree on that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

MSDN says: The loading functionality of LINQ to XML is built upon XmlReader.Therefore, you might catch any exceptions that are thrown by the XmlReader. Create overload methods and the XmlReader methods that read and parse the document.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756wd7zs.aspx
ArgumentNullException and SecurityException

EDIT: MSDN not always says true. So I've analyzed Load method code with reflector and got results like this:

```
public static XDocument Load(XmlReader reader)
{
    return Load(reader, LoadOptions.None);
}
```

Method Load is calling method:

```
public static XDocument Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
{
    if (reader == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("reader"); //ArgumentNullException
    }
    if (reader.ReadState == ReadState.Initial)
    {
        reader.Read();// Could throw XmlException according to MSDN
    }
    XDocument document = new XDocument();
    if ((options & LoadOptions.SetBaseUri) != LoadOptions.None)
    {
        string baseURI = reader.BaseURI;
        if ((baseURI != null) && (baseURI.Length != 0))
        {
            document.SetBaseUri(baseURI);
        }
    }
    if ((options & LoadOptions.SetLineInfo) != LoadOptions.None)
    {
        IXmlLineInfo info = reader as IXmlLineInfo;
        if ((info != null) && info.HasLineInfo())
        {
            document.SetLineInfo(info.LineNumber, info.LinePosition);
        }
    }
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
    {
        document.Declaration = new XDeclaration(reader);
    }
    document.ReadContentFrom(reader, options); // InvalidOperationException
    if (!reader.EOF)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(Res.GetString("InvalidOperation_ExpectedEndOfFile")); // InvalidOperationException
    }
    if (document.Root == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(Res.GetString("InvalidOperation_MissingRoot")); // InvalidOperationException
    }
    return document;
}
```

Lines with exceptions possibility are commented

We could get the next exceptions:ArgumentNullException, XmlException and InvalidOperationException.
MSDN says that you could get SecurityException, but perhaps you can get this type of exception while creating XmlReader.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately I know that malformed xml would throw some other errors as well (I have seen them on occasion).

Comment: I am sorry for incorrect answer! I've analized XDocument.Load(XmlReader) with reflector, and found out thet there could be more 2 exceptions  InvalidOperationException and XmlException. MSDN not always says true (

Comment: Hey man!  Nice follow up.  I really appreciate it.  I haven't explored reflection yet.  That was very helpful.  Marking as answer.

Answer (score 3):

`XmlReader.Create(Stream)` allows two types of exceptions: [*[src]*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756wd7zs.aspx)

```
XmlReader reader; // Do whatever you want

try
{
  XDocument.Load(reader);
}
catch (ArgumentNullException)
{
  // The input value is null.
}
catch (SecurityException)
{
  // The XmlReader does not have sufficient permissions 
  // to access the location of the XML data.
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
  // The underlying file of the path cannot be found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the online documentation doesn't state which exceptions it throws... too bad.
You will save yourself some grief with FileNotFoundException's by using a FileInfo instance, and calling its **Exists** method to make sure the file really is there. That way you won't have to catch that type of exception.
[Edit]
Upon re-reading your post, I forgot to notice that you are passing in an XML Reader. My response was based upon passing in a string that represents a file (overloaded method). 
In light of that, I would (like the other person who responded to your question had a good answer too).

In light of the missing exception list, I would suggest to make a test file with malformed XML and try loading it to see what type of exceptions really do get thrown. Then handle those cases.

Comment: Unless someone is able to provide a list for me, I think this may be my only option.  It sure would be nice to have a list in the documentation though.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Checking with File.Exists is not a wise method of preventing `FileNotFoundException`, it simply creates a race condition. The **only** reliable way to guarantee the existence of a file is to actually try to open the file and catch the `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Read my post. I never suggested using File.Exists. I suggested using a FileInfo instance. Please don't come in here months after the conversation is finished and dock me when you never contributed to the original conversation in the first place.

Comment: And Aaron, you never explained why it creates a race condition. The burdon of proof is on you, not me.

Answer (score 0):

I was following a tutorial about [web scraping in .NET 6 using XDocument](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/easily-do-web-scraping-in-net-core-6-0/). However, when I called `XDocument.Load("...")` to load an .html page, I got the following exception:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: ''src' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 47, position 32.'
```

So depending on what you will parse, and if you need something more permissive, perhaps another library is more suited. I went with [IronWebScraper](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/webscraper/), which works better for the HTML I am working with.