# XML read write ('System.Xml.XmlException is thrown)

Tags: c#, xml

```
class Customers
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long MobileNo { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();



    // UserInput
    public void InsertCustomer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Id");
        CustId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Name");
        Name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Mobile No");
        MobileNo = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Location");
        Location = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Address");
        Address = Console.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(@"CustomersDetail.xml");

            if (doc.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
            {
                // It is empty 
                XDocument xDoc = 
                    new XDocument(    
                        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),  
                        new XComment("LINQ To XML Demo"),       
                        new XElement("Customers",           
                        new XElement("Customer",           
                        new XElement("CustId", CustId),     
                        new XElement("Name", Name),         
                        new XElement("MobileNo", MobileNo),  
                        new XElement("Location", Location),   
                        new XElement("Address", Address))));


                xDoc.Save(stringWriter);
                xDoc.Save(@"CustomersDetail.xml");
                Console.WriteLine("\n Created new XML \n" + stringWriter);
            }
            else if (doc.ChildNodes.Count > 1)
            {

                //if (xDoc.ChildNodes.Count > 1)
                // There are more children on the **root level** of the DOM
                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"CustomersDetail.xml");

                xdoc.Element("Customers").Add(
                    new XElement("Customer",
                        new XElement("CustId", CustId),
                        new XElement("Name", Name),
                        new XElement("MobileNo", MobileNo),
                        new XElement("Location", Location),
                        new XElement("Address", Address)));

                xdoc.Save(stringWriter);
                xdoc.Save(@"CustomersDetail.xml");
                Console.WriteLine("\n Added \n" + stringWriter);
            }
        }
        catch(XmlException exc)
        {
            //invalid file
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry");

        }

    }

}
```

i am trying create XML Db

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
XDocument xDoc = 
                    new XDocument(    
                        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),  
                        new XComment("LINQ To XML Demo"),       
                        new XElement("Customers",           
                        new XElement("Customer",           
                        new XElement("CustId", CustId),     
                        new XElement("Name", Name),         
                        new XElement("MobileNo", MobileNo),  
                        new XElement("Location", Location),   
                        new XElement("Address", Address))));


                xDoc.Save(stringWriter);
                xDoc.Save(@"CustomersDetail.xml");
                Console.WriteLine("\n Created new XML \n" + stringWriter);
```

I Run this code working , but rerun the code it loose my previous data and new data on .

then new code for add new data on existing XML

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"CustomersDetail.xml");

                xdoc.Element("Customers").Add(
                    new XElement("Customer",
                        new XElement("CustId", CustId),
                        new XElement("Name", Name),
                        new XElement("MobileNo", MobileNo),
                        new XElement("Location", Location),
                        new XElement("Address", Address)));

                xdoc.Save(stringWriter);
                xdoc.Save(@"CustomersDetail.xml");
                Console.WriteLine("\n Added \n" + stringWriter);
```

but Run this code

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"CustomersDetail.xml");

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Root element is missing.

Help Me

Comment: What does the file look like when you try to run that line?

Comment: file is empty nothing on their

Comment: Then it seems the error message is correct. What do you want to do if there is an empty file?

Comment: Your code works for me, though I took out the save to `StringWriter`. What is the point of that?

Comment: @SentilSebastian - your exception is probably cause by the fact that, in a previous run of your program, you created an invalid XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

1. You are loading into an `XmlDocument`, then loading into an `XDocument`.  There is no reason to do this.  Pick one, preferably the latter.
2. You call `doc.Load(@"CustomersDetail.xml");` but do not catch any exception thrown.  If the file does not exist, this method will throw a `FileNotFoundException`.  (I notice that [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not state this explicitly.  This seems to be an oversight on the part of Microsoft.)  Also, if in an earlier run of your program, invalid XML was written to  `"CustomersDetail.xml"`, subsequent calls to `doc.Load()` will throw an `XmlException`.  (An empty file, for instance, is invalid XML.)  So you might want to catch that also.
3. In an `XmlDocument`, to check to see whether the root node has been created yet, check if [`XmlDocument.DocumentElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `null`.  In an `XDocument`, check if [`XDocument.Root`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `null`.
4. You should separate your user interface method from your "save" method, and eliminate duplicated in-lined hardcoded strings like `@"CustomersDetail.xml"`.
5. In `InsertCustomer()`, [`long.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b6b4bx3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can throw a variety of exceptions on bad user input.  You should consider handling those exceptions.

Thus:

```
class Customers
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long MobileNo { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    internal const string XmlFileName = @"CustomersDetail.xml";

    private void AddToDB()
    {
        XDocument xdoc;
        if (!XDocumentExtensions.TryLoad(XmlFileName, out xdoc))
            // File does not exist.  Create it.
            xdoc = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                new XComment("LINQ To XML Demo"));

        if (xdoc.Root == null)
            xdoc.Add(new XElement("Customers"));

        xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement("Customer",
                        new XElement("CustId", CustId),
                        new XElement("Name", Name),
                        new XElement("MobileNo", MobileNo),
                        new XElement("Location", Location),
                        new XElement("Address", Address)));

        try
        {
            xdoc.Save(XmlFileName);
            Console.WriteLine("\n Added \n" + xdoc.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // No documented specific exception types from XDocument.Save() either.
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to write to XML file {0}", XmlFileName));
        }
    }

    // UserInput
    public void InsertCustomer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Id");
        CustId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Name");
        Name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Mobile No");
        MobileNo = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Location");
        Location = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Address");
        Address = Console.ReadLine();

        AddToDB();
    }
}
```

Using

```
public static class XDocumentExtensions
{
    public static bool TryLoad(string fileName, out XDocument doc)
    {
        try
        {
            doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
            return true;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            // File does not exist yet, so we must create it.
            doc = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Some other internal error.
            // XDocument.Load() has no documented specific exception types :(
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904907/xdocument-loadxmlreader-possible-exceptions
            // So we could either catch these or pass them upwards.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            doc = null;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```